# Official encrypted wallet generator

Tags: cold-storage, encryption, core-development-team

I'd like to make a cold storage wallet such that if it is found it will appear to be an empty wallet unless a password is used to decrypt it. This site xmr.llcoins.net was recommended by moderators, but it still seems like an unofficial method, and I'm worried about decryption method being lost. Also if it hasn't been tested thoroughly I'd hate to send xmr to nowhere and have it lost.

Is there any plan for an official encrypted wallet generator to be run/distributed by core team?

I would like any encrypted wallet to itself be a valid wallet. You could create an arbitrary tree inside with different passwords for duress situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheme from the site is a good one and it won't be lost if you don't lose it :)

But anyways, it's fairly simple to remember: hash the passphrase with CryptoNight and EC add it to the original seed. Even if lost, knowing the scheme, it could be reimplemented.

This method has the benefit you seek -  encrypted seed looking like any other. You could roll a random seed, and then make multiple other seeds from it by applying different passphrases. Store only the "main" one, and put some pocket change on it to fool a potential thief into thinking that's all there is.

There's acutally already a PR to implement the same method into "official" software: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2257

Comment: When you say "hash with cryptonite" does that mean there's only one cryptonite equation? It's not a general term like , do some math on it? Like an md5 checksum is an md5 checksum across any computer, always same result?